# How can I use a switch() statement to convert from a numeric to a letter grade?

Tags: java, switch-statement

This IS NOT homework, but it is a practice that the teacher gave us to help study for a test. But i will not be turning this in to the teacher. (i'm hoping that is allowed)

He wants a user to input a grade and have it assigned a letter grade. It would be easy with if statements, but i can't use ANY! I have to use the switch method.

Here is my functional class:

```
public class Grade {

public double getGrade(int input)
 {
  double inputGrade;
  switch(input)
  {
   case 1: inputGrade >= 90;
       break;
   case 2: inputGrade >= 80;
       break;
   case 3: inputGrade >= 70;
       break;
   default:
       grade = 60;
  }
  return grade;

 }

}
```

Here is my test class:

```
import java.util.*;
public class TestGrade
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  int input = scan.nextInt();
  Grade lGrade = new Grade();
  double finalGrade = lGrade.getGradeSwitch(input);
  System.out.println("Your toll is $" + finalGrade);
 }

}
```

I just haven't been programming enough to have this analytical mind. I HAVE tried to complete it, i just haven't found a way to covert the user input (int) into a letter grade (string) without if statements.

I know this is incomplete, but this is as far as I could go without making errors.

EDIT:WOW! Thanks guys, i hate to pick a single correct answer, because a lot of  you helped me!

This is what i ended up with (that worked :D)

```
public String getGrade(int input)
{
    String letterGrade;
    switch(input/10)
    {
        case 9: letterGrade = "A";
                  break;
        case 8: letterGrade = "B";
                  break;
        case 7: letterGrade = "C";
                  break;
        case 6: letterGrade = "D";
        default:
                  letterGrade = "F";
    }
    return letterGrade;

}
```

Comment: Homework is allowed, though generally it's nice if people tag it as such. Or even writing the question in such a way that shows you've put thought into it rather than just copy/paste the question out of your excercise.

Comment: Amen to what Matthew said. +1 for the effort, even though I often find homework questions less than acceptable.

Comment: Wow.  You have to love arbitrary rules such as "you must use a switch statement".  That really reflects the real world.  I mean, wouldn't it have been better if the teacher actually came up with a question more suited to actually using a switch statement.  I mean, you could probably write a solution using just while loops, but you never would.

Comment: Also, Phil, another major point of learning here is *learn math!!!*. The analysis of the solution is fairly easy with some level of discrete math knowledge, and that class (as well as a couple of other math ones) should be at the top of your class list.

Comment: Yeah, I think mathematically i had it correct originally, but it got a little screwy with all the updates and modifications

Comment: @Kibbee - I must dis-agree. it's a good "non-trivial" exercise for learning about switch. It's not 100% straightforward, it has >1 solution, and it promotes what the OP termed "analytical mind" instead of cookie cutter copy/paste programming

Comment: I scored 100% and got an F :(

Comment: haha Thanks Jack :D added case 10 = A. 

I'm NOT a programmer!!

Comment: @Phil: ... lesson #N from this: Read ALL of your specifications :)
Nested in the middle of my fine print in the answer was "aside from 100" wording :)
Seriously, if you learn to pay very meticulous (OCD level) attention to details, you will become an order of magnitude better developer long term. Half the job is remembering every tricky little detail.

Comment: Won't the compiler optimize the `switch` into `if-else` statements anyway?

Comment: @Cory - Actually, it will probably optimize the `switch` into a jump table. But that's entirely beside the point - it is an excercise on how to teach someone to solve a slightly non-orthodox problem AND to use switch.

Comment: Is it just me, or does the code above need a `break` after `letterGrade = "D";` line?

Comment: It needs a `break` after `letterGrade = "D";` and should have one after `letterGrade = "F"` for ease of reading/editing.

Comment: guys, this was 4 years ago, give it a rest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, my assumption is that you will enter a numeric grade 0-100, and that the letter grades you want go as "90-100: A; 80-89: B; ...; 60-69: D; 0-59: F".

If that is not the case, your first lesson to be learned about programming is: **the most important part of coding is clearly writing out specifications and requirements**

Having said that, there are smart and dumb approaches.

- Dumb approach:

  - Use a switch on the "input" as you do now
  - Since values 90, 91... 100 are all supposed to be treated the same, put them all in as separate switch cases **but only do the work in the last one** (known as fall-through; [see SwitchDemo2 on this page for how that works](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html))
  - For the last value (say, 90 if you start from 100 and go down), the switch statement would be letterGrade = "A"; break;
  - once you reach case of 89, you repeat the same logic as you did for 100 through 90
  - Lather, Rinse, Repeat, till 60
  - Handle Fs as a default case.

This will be very long, quite dumb (as in, brute force) and very annoying to write, and a brilliant teaching tool for why you never want to write dumb code again if you can help it.

- More elegant solution (*insert appropriate Star Wars quote here*)

  - What do you see in common between every # that correspons to "A"?

  Right, it's the fact that, aside from 100, they all are 2-diit #s starting with 9.

  So, to handle them all in 1 case statement, wouldn't it be wonderful to switch on some value that gives you "9" for all #s between 90 and 99?

  I hope you know the answer right away... hint below...

  Yes, just divide whole by 10!

  So, you need to have a switch on your numeric grade diveded by 10,
  with cases of 10, 9, 8, 7, 6 and default mapping to F.

Hope this covers enough ground for you to come up with working solution, while showing how the analysis might work as well.

Comment: NOTE: I will not critique your current code - the main problem with it was already commented on by another answer and minor syntactic issues are not really the whole point of this Q as I see it.

Comment: NOTE: an even smarter way is to avoid SWITCH alltogether, and use (as another answer suggested) the power of ASCII codes... but that is a wee bit advanced and really really violates the spirit of this excercise which is to learn switching.

Answer (score 3):

I commented this as thoroughly as I could. Hopefully you will be able to follow along. As this is not a homework question, I have no problem posting a solution. Sometimes you just need to see the code to "get it", so here it is. If you have any questions about what I've written, leave a comment and I'll clarify the answer.

```
public static String getGrade(int numberGrade) {
    // There are two parts of the number grade that you really 
    // care about. The first is the quotient after division 
    // by 10. The second is the remainder after division by 
    // 10. The quotient will tell you where it is an A, B, C
    // D, or F. The remainder will tell you whether it should 
    // have a +, -, or nothing following the letter.
    // 
    // Let's take the grade 73 as an example. The quotient would 
    // be 7, with a remainder of 3. Because it has a quotient of 
    // 7, you know it's a C. Because of the 3, you know it should 
    // have a minus sign (-) after it.
    //
    // Once you know the pattern, you can pretty easily apply 
    // a switch statement to it and produce a letter grade.

    // Variables for the quotient and remainder, described above
    int quotient = numberGrade / 10;
    int remainder = numberGrade % 10;

    // This will hold the final letter grade
    String letterGrade;

    switch (quotient) {
        case 10:
            // The student got a 100%, so just return A+
            return "A+";
        case 9:
            // 90-99 is an A
            letterGrade = "A"; break;
        case 8:
            // 80-89 is a B
            letterGrade = "B"; break;
        case 7:
            // 70-79 is a C
            letterGrade = "C"; break;
        case 6:
            // 60-69 is a D
            letterGrade = "D"; break;
        default:
            // Anything 59 or below is an F
            return "F";
    }

    switch (remainder) {
        // For example, 70-73 are C-
        case 0: case 1: case 2: case 3:
            letterGrade += "-"; break;
        // Likewise, 77-79 are C+
        case 7: case 8: case 9:
            letterGrade += "+"; break;
        // Everything else just falls through, no + or - needed
    }

    // You are left with a letter grade consisting of 
    // an A, B, C, D or F, and a plus or minus where 
    // it is appropriate.
    return letterGrade;
}
```

And here is a really simple demonstration of this method:

```
for (int i = 100; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.println(i + " = " + getGrade(i));
}
```

It will print the following:

```
100 = A+
 99 = A+
 98 = A+
 97 = A+
 96 = A
 95 = A
 94 = A
 93 = A-
 92 = A-
 91 = A-
 90 = A-
 89 = B+
 88 = B+
 87 = B+
 86 = B
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much for your explanation!! I didn't just copy/paste, i really learned here thanks!

Comment: This is brilliant as it handles an extra case +'s and -'s.

Answer (score 1):

The switch statement does not take conditional values, ie it doesnt look for a `true` or `false` answer like `inputGrade >= 70;`, instead it looks for whether the item *`n`* in `switch(`*`n`*`)` is equal to *`x`* of the `case`*`x`*`:`.

Also, switch cases end with colons (`:`), not semis.

See [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_Java.2C_php) for a generic explanation of the switch statement with a specific Java example.

Comment: @akf - while your answer is very useful for the syntactic side of it, I feel that the user is also asking for "how to approach the analysis" part as well. Just my feeling.

Comment: I agree.  There are a bunch of solutions out there already making a couple very good points (/10 for ex (almost too good, perhaps)).  I was obviously targeting the 'getting the head around the switch first' aspect as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another hint as to how to do this.

What would happen if you integer divided the grade by 10?

Answer (score 1):

Switch statements only work with values matching the given cases (along with a default).
The only way to write this using a switch statement is to have a case for every possible score.

You would do this like:

```
switch (score)
{
    case 0:
    case 1:
    ...
    case 80:
    case 81:         
    ...
    case 89:
      return "B";
    case 90:
    ...
    case 100:
      return "A";
      break;
}
```

OR

You can cut it down to a a list of 11 possible cases by dividing by 10 first.

That would leave you with:

```
switch (score / 10)
{
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
       return "F";
    case 5:
       return "E";
    case 6:
       return "D";
    case 7:
       return "C";
    case 8:
       return "B";
    case 9:
    case 10:
       return "A";
}
```

Or something similar (of course this assumes you have grades corresponding to 50+ = E, 90+ = A and so on).

Comment: Heh... great minds and all... but why didn't you use defaults?
Also, it'd be a good idea to give HINTS instead of working code, as the kid is supposed to learn to fish.

Comment: You really only need to account for each number grade to 60 to 100. Everything else is an F.

Comment: @DVK- I gave it about 30 seconds thought, didn't really think about cleaning it up to use defaults etc. You're probably right about the fishing thing - but I think the problem is kind of like telling the kid to go catch a blue whale using a piece of spaghetti. Assuming he is a kid, and not a mature-age student. And a he.

Comment: @William - I didn't see that in the requirements, but this was a real simple example of how you would go about it. It isn't meant to be the correct answer.

If I had to do this for real, my final code would probably look pretty different (plus I'd challenge the switch-only restriction).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a starting point: The 'A' character, as an integer, has the value 65. What do you suppose happens if you convert the value 66 to a character?

Answer (score 0):

make this correction

```
  double grade; // i think you mispelled it inputGrade
```

and

```
   case 1: grade = 90; // inputGrade >= 90 is an expression and is not valid
       break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you covered [Enums](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html) yet? My suggestion would be to think about how an enumeration might help you get at your answer. Sorry, I can't give you any more help than that without ruining your aha moment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere in your code where you will return back a letter.

You may want to write it out in English, somewhat, and see what you are missing.

For example:
User inputs numeric grade
Numeric grade is converted into a letter grade
Print out numeric and letter grade.

Then, write out the main tough part, part 2.
Possible grades are ...
Possible input ranges are ...
Return letter grade

If you write it our more clearly, very step-by-step, as that is how the computer will process it, then you should see how to do it.

Pretend you are explaining to a second-grader how to do this, it has to be very basic instructions.

Comment: @James: but... my compiler is a lot dumber than a second grader. It ALWAYS fails to Do What I Mean - second graders sometimes do that right :)

Answer (score 0):

First off, if your function is to take a grade as an integer and return a letter grade, why does it have a return type of `double`?

After dealing with that, here is a hint:

The grade could range from 0 to 100, so that is 101 cases to handle in your switch statement. So you could write out all 101 cases if you wanted. But, can you think of a way to reduce the number of cases? (big hint: all grade boundaries are a multiple of 10)

Answer (score 0):

I was bored and came up with this.  I know it doesn't use switch statements either, but anywho:

```
    private string GetGrade(int grade)
    {
        return ((char)((int)(Math.Max((Math.Min(10 - (grade / 10) + 64, 69)), 65))))
               .ToString().Replace("E", "F");
    }
```

I just wanted to see if I could do it using character codes.  There's probably an even shorter way, but oh well :)  Oh, and sorry, it's C#.

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
static int[]     SCORES =
    { 90, 80, 70, 60, 0 };  

static String[]  GRADES =
    { "A", "B", "C", "D", "F" };  

String letterGrade(int pct)
{
    for (int i = 0;  i < SCORES.length;  i++)
        if (pct >= SCORES[i])
            return GRADES[i];
}
```

This assumes that `pct` is positive. It uses a single `if` statement, so I'm not sure if this qualifies as a valid solution or not.

Comment: While it's artificial, the constraint on the question is to use a switch and no if's.